# angular JS + Spring rest + file attachment

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I want to upload file using angular 1 and spring rest but along with file want to sent DTO object(jackson api converting json to java dto object at spring rest service class) can any one please suggest what is solution for that, I tried few things but it is not working at all

here is code looks like

```
angular code : 
var vm = this;  
vm.reportIssueDTO = {};
vm.reportIssueDTO.appUserName     = firstName + " " + lastName;
vm.reportIssueDTO.appEmail        = userName;
vm.reportIssueDTO.environment     = environment;
vm.reportIssueDTO.version         = majorVersion + "." + buildVersion;
vm.reportIssueDTO.webpageLocation = $location.absUrl(); 
vm.reportIssueDTO.webpageLocation = $location.absUrl();
vm.reportIssueDTO.userAgent       = navigator.userAgent;        

reportNewIssue(vm.reportIssueDTO, vm.issueFile).then(function(response){
    showSuccessMessage();
}

function reportNewIssue(reportIssueDTO, file) {         
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append("reportIssueDTO", reportIssueDTO);

    var httpParams = {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type" : undefined
            },
            transformRequest : angular.identity
    };          
    return $http.post("api/app/reportissue", formData, httpParams);
}   

spring rest code :
@RequestMapping(value = "/reportissue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JsonNode reportIssue(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "reportIssueDTO") String reportIssueDTO) {
}
```

I am getting reportIssueDTO as a string now by current code but I want as object , can any one please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Of course it's a String, the parameter in your method `reportIssue` is a String. Try to set it to your object `ReportIssueDTO`. Spring should use Jackson internally to map the incoming data to the object.

Comment: Use the right tag please, [angularjs] and not [angular] (which refers to angular 2 and above)

Comment: resolved by formData.append("reportIssueDTO", JSON.stringify(reportIssueDTO)); converting data to json stringify then at rest server side by Object mapper like this : reportIssueDTO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(reportIssueDTOStr, ReportIssueDTO.class);

Comment: pass the DTO in request body and capture it in @RequestBody where the ObjectMapper will automatically map UI param into DTO.